# How to get value seconds in datetime.timedelta

Tags: python

I've a variable td of type datetime.timedelta and i've to get the value of seconds alongside days hours and minutes,

here td is equal to `-3 days, 8:55:52.210629`
i'm getting days, hours and minutes by `td.days, td.seconds // 3600, (td.seconds // 60) % 60` as `-3 8 55`, i also want to get the value 52 here as well.

what action should i perform to get this. plz help me out on this

Comment: Well, what value do you see for `td.seconds`? What is the mathematical rule that tells you, the part of that number, that doesn't represent a whole number of minutes? (Hint: how many seconds are in a minute? Are there any smaller divisions of time that you need to worry about?) (Hint: when you wrote `td.seconds // 3600` and `(td.seconds // 60) % 60`, **how did you come up with those?**)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
c.seconds % 60
```

should be the answer.
Takes the difference in seconds between the two given times.

```
a = datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 21, 18, 25, 52)
b = datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 16, 8, 21, 10)

# returns a timedelta object
c = a-b
c.seconds % 60
42
```